# Disparity between outputs that Rally loopback API returns and what is seen on the Rally GUI

Tags: rally

There is a disparity between what is on rally and what the loopback API is returning. If you look at the screen shots below I see that Rally CORRECTLY has "BE" as the project for a defect however, if you look at what is returned using SDK shows "FE." Why is this happening? In fact, I see "FE" as the project name for all the defects pulled using Rally SDK. Here is my code too if it helps.  Thanks Kay!

```
   _82openDefect: function() {
    this.chart = {
            xtype: 'rallychart',
            storeType: 'Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',
            storeConfig: this._82getStoreForopenDefect(),
            calculatorType: 'Rally.example.CFDCalculator',
            calculatorConfig: {
                  stateFieldName: 'Severity',
                  stateFieldValues: ['P1 - Crash/Data Loss, upgrade/migration fail', 
                                     'P2 - Major Problem, loss of stability or feature functionality', 
                                     'P3 - Minor Problem, improves customer experience',
                                     'P4 - Cosmetic, okay to defer'
                                     ]
            },
            width: 1000,
            height: 600,
            chartConfig: this._82getopenDefectConfig()
        };
    this.chartContainer.add(this.chart);
},

_82getStoreForopenDefect: function() {
    return {
        find: {
            _TypeHierarchy: { '$in' : [ 'Defect' ] },
            Children: null,
            _ProjectHierarchy: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
            _ValidFrom: {'$gt': Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(Rally.util.DateTime.add(new Date(), 'day', -120)) },
            State: "Open",
            Release: 19388025787,
            Severity: "P1 - Crash/Data Loss, upgrade/migration fail",
        },
        fetch: ['Severity','Release','Project','SubmittedBy','Name'],
        hydrate: ['Severity','Release','Project','SubmittedBy','Name'],
        sort: {
            _ValidFrom: 1
        },
        context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
        limit: Infinity
    };
},

_82getopenDefectConfig: function() {
    console.log("starting 8.2 open defect chart");
    return {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: '8.2 Open Defects'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            tickInterval: 20,
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                title: {
                    text: 'Count'
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        }
    };
},
```

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to say for sure what you're seeing, but is it possible that the defect was moved from FE to BE sometime after August?  The name in the results ("Consuming amp device events messages from postgres") also doesn't match the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I do see that the defect was moved from FE to BE in September. Question that arises now is how is the LBAPI pulling its data? Shouldn't it pull Project as "BE?". Another, vital point, I am getting project as "FE" for ALL the defects! This is not possible. How can everything be in "FE?" Because on Rally GUI I do see that projects such as "BE," "VisualRF," etc.   Thank you! -Kay